# Avoiding having SIP permanently disabled to permit kernel extension

Tags: big-sur, kernel-extensions

I'm looking to work around the lack of support for a wireless adapter in Big Sur by using https://github.com/chris1111/Wireless-USB-Big-Sur-Adapter/. Unfortunately it requires SIP to be disabled not just during installation, [but permanently](https://github.com/chris1111/Wireless-USB-Big-Sur-Adapter/issues/59#issuecomment-768992076). I'm trying to understand why that is, and whether there might be alternatives?

For instance, HoRDNS which faced similar problems you only need to temporarily disable it (https://github.com/jwise/HoRNDIS/issues/132)

Does anyone have any suggestions? My understanding of how all the kext stuff works is a little limited.

Answer (score 1):

You can selectively enable parts of System Integrity Protection.

For example, you can enable all of SIP except kernel extension protection with

```
csrutil enable --without kext
```

Some other options to try listed in https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/17452, but the kext option sounds the most promising.